# Destination with the same identifier name {xtheorem.1}

Tags: hyperref, numbering, theorems

I have the warning

> destination with the same identifier (name{xtheorem.1}) has been
>   already used, duplicate ignored \relax l.31
>   \begin{definition}[DefinitionInChapterTwo]

Although there are many questions about "destination with the same identifier", I could not find one according to the identifier `xtheorem`.

The problem only occurs when I use `\begin{definition}` in more than one chapter so I think within one chapter, the identifiers are unique but not in the whole document...

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newlistof[chapter]{theorems}{lthm}{\theoremsname}

\newcommand\addtotheorems[2]{
    \refstepcounter{theorems}
    \addcontentsline{lthm}{theorems}{\protect\numberline{\thetheorems}\textbf{#1:} #2}
}

\usepackage{shadethm}
\newshadetheorem{xtheorem}{Satz}[chapter]
\newshadetheorem{xdefinition}[xtheorem]{Definition}

\newenvironment{definition}[1][]{%
    \addtotheorems{Definition}{#1}
    \begin{xdefinition}[#1]%
    }{\end{xdefinition}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title1}
\section{Section 1-1}

\begin{definition}[DefinitionInChapterOne]
\end{definition}

\chapter{Title2}
\section{Section 2-1}

\begin{definition}[DefinitionInChapterTwo]
\end{definition} 

\end{document}
```

Could you please tell me where I have to make changes to get this issue working?

---

Update: I figured out that it has something to do with line `\newshadetheorem{xtheorem}{Satz}[chapter]`
This gives me (chapter number).(counter per chapter). But in my mind, this is unique!?! Isn't it?
If I change `chapter` to `section`, I got a theorem number like 1.1.1 what obviously means (chapter number).(section number).(counter per section)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `shadethm` I'd give a look at `tcolorbox`. Anyway, you just need to define `\theHxtheorem`, which `hyperref` will use for setting anchors.

Load `hyperref` last.

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{shadethm}

\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

\newlistof[chapter]{theorems}{lthm}{\theoremsname}

\newcommand\addtotheorems[2]{% <-- don't forget
    \refstepcounter{theorems}% <-- don't forget
    \addcontentsline{lthm}{theorems}{\protect\numberline{\thetheorems}\textbf{#1:} #2}% <-- don't forget
}

\newshadetheorem{xtheorem}{Satz}[chapter]
\newshadetheorem{xdefinition}[xtheorem]{Definition}
% keep hyperref happy
\newcommand{\theHxtheorem}{\thechapter.\arabic{xtheorem}}

\newenvironment{definition}[1][]
 {\addtotheorems{Definition}{#1}\begin{xdefinition}[#1]}
 {\end{xdefinition}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title1}
\section{Section 1-1}

\begin{definition}[DefinitionInChapterOne]
\end{definition}

\chapter{Title2}
\section{Section 2-1}

\begin{definition}[DefinitionInChapterTwo]
\end{definition} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much! I really appreciate your help. :-) But I do not understand the actual problem. I've read about, that if \xtheorem is a counter, \thextheorem gives me its current value. But what is \theHxtheorem ? And furthermore: Do I have to check my already existing references because of any possible side effects?

Comment: @lukasl1991 I didn't look at what `\newshadedtheorem` does. Apparently it doesn't behave with `hyperref` even if loaded before it. Anyway, if `foo` is a counter and the command `\theHfoo` is defined, `hyperref` will use it for the sole purpose of setting the internal anchor.

Comment: What are these "% <-- don't forget" for?

Comment: @lukasl1991 Avoid spurious spaces in the output.